# Warning thrown by Python with inheritance of TestCase - 'Need more values to unpack'

Tags: django, unit-testing

In **Django unittest**, I am inheriting from a custom class to provide some generic helper functions for all TestCases. The custom class then inherits from TestCase (from django.test). Code look like this:

```
class APITest(TestManager):

    def setUp(self):
        self.User, self.api_client = super(APITest, self).setUp()
```

Test Manager looks like this:

```
class TestManager(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do some stuff
```

Warning is shown on the call to `super(APITest, self).setUp()`- **Need more values to unpack**

The goal of having TestManager inherit from TestCase as well is to give it access to TestCase **assert** methods (to collect a bit more information on test results).

The code still runs fine, yet this warning makes me worry if this implementation is correct or can be improved. Also i dont understand the error, since the call to super still works and returns 2 values.

NOTE: Initially, TestManager did not inherit from TestCase and no warning was shown.

So it's really a 2 part question: Why is this error occuring? Is there a design flaw present here which can be improved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a generic setup to your tests, you could add a class method to your `TestManager` called `setUpClass` like this:

```
class TestManager(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # generic setup here.

class APITest(TestManager):
    def setUp(self):
        # specific (and additional) setup here.
```

the same logic works for `tearDown` and `tearDownClass`.

### Regerding your design ...

Just inherit `APITest` from `TestManager`:

```
class APITest(TestManager):
    def setUp(self):
        # do some stuff
```

In the end, that's the purpose of `TestManager`, right?  Make its functions available to the other tests.

The class `APITest` will have the methods from `TestCase` too, since `TestManager` inherits from it.

Comment: No, its the other way around -- I want APITest and all other "Test Cases' to inherit from TestManager

Comment: Ok, I change the names, but you get the idea, right?

Comment: Tried, that -- Same warning appears. Although i believe that's a better design (I will edit post to your suggestion)

Comment: In fact the TestCase will run just fine, however the warning appears